# GatsbyJS with Tailwind CSS PrismJS Syntax Not Highlighting

Tags: tailwind-css, gatsby, prismjs, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I've run into a bit of an issue. I have a project using Tailwind CSS and I'd like to add syntax highlighting to my markdown so I've added PrismJS to the project. For a reason I can't understand the PrismJS highlighting hasn't kicked in.

It adds in the code blocks, but it doesn't seem to use the PrismJS themes. It just adds a dark background for the blocks with light-coloured text all the same colour. I've added a require statement to my gatsby-browser.js:

`require("prismjs/themes/prism-solarizedlight.css")` 
This seems to change the colour of the text, again though, it's just the same colour text so not really highlighting the syntax.

For reference this is an example of me attempting to use the highlighting in an mdx file:

```js
//testing
function foo(bar) {
  var a = 42,
    b = 'Prism';
  return a + bar(b);
}
```

And this is how I've added PrismJS to my gatsby-config.js:

`{ resolve:` gatsby-transformer-remark`, options: { plugins: [ { resolve:` gatsby-remark-prismjs`, options: { classPrefix: "language-", inlineCodeMarker: null, aliases: {}, showLineNumbers: false, noInlineHighlight: false, languageExtensions: [ { language: "superscript", extend: "javascript", definition: { superscript_types: /(SuperType)/, }, insertBefore: { function: { superscript_keywords: /(superif|superelse)/, }, }, }, ], prompt: { user: "root", host: "localhost", global: false, }, escapeEntities: {}, }, }, ], }, }`

I'm a bit lost with this so any help would be really appreciated. If you need any more information let me know and I'd be happy to provide.

I've tried adding several of the prismjs themes, I've also tried to add in my own custom CSS but I'm not sure if I'm doing that right.
I'm expecting a level of syntax highlighting for different languages